# Cant not Limit IK Bone Rotation of bone

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I Need help with the rig

The image is when i using the boneIK to control finger ,The thumb2 work alright,but the thumb1 rotation out of where it should . Does IK limit rotation just work when theres connected parent?

*on the right is thumb1.r bone properties show the blue circle it should rotate *

[Here's the File](https://mega.nz/folder/cI0UxQBS#GiX58qo-5ofYiyz7hQUYCg)
[image]Thank you!

Comment: could you please specify which bone you mean, what the result is and what result you expect? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IK angle limits are not respected on the first bone of IK chains with pole targets.  You have to choose between letting angle limits control the first bone, or letting the pole target control the first bone.

Generally speaking, the less ways that you complicate IK, with angle limits and pole targets and such, the better those IK chains are going to function.  Many uses of angle limits are going to end up creating IK twitch whenever they come into play.

Most of my own IK chains do not have pole targets.  Thumbs are one where I typically do use pole targets, on a 3-bone chain.  But angle limits are not necessary on them; the initial metacarpal is the only bone that rotates in more angles than a simple hinge.  Control of the initial bone can be tuned by IK stiffness and by placing the IK target and pole in reasonable positions.